# My SQL PHP Multi Layer Drop Down List from Databse

Tags: php, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

Hello Help Much Appreciated. 
I am having trouble figuring this out. I cannot find tutorials anywhere with this specific task.
I have one table with ID, Manufacturer, ModelNo, Manupartcode and more fields.

I want first drop down list to be populated with Manufacturer.
SELECT Manufacturer FROM Table_Name;
This is fine

The second list need to be ModelNo.
SELECT ModelNo FROM Table_Name WHERE Manufacturer = 'What We picked from first list';

```
INDEX.PHP

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showData(str) 
{
    if (str == "") 
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","showData.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('Server_Name', 'Username', 'Password', 'Database_Name') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("select DISTINCT Manufacturer from Table_Name");

    echo "<select name = 'Manufacturer' onchange = 'showData(this.value)'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                  unset($Manufacturer);
                  $Manufacturer = $row['Manufacturer']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$Manufacturer.'">'.$Manufacturer.'</option>';

}

    echo "</select>";
?>
</form>

<br>

<div id="txtHint">
    Text
</div>

</body>
</html>


SHOWDATA.PHP

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('Server_Name', 'Username', 'Password', 'Database_Name');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"Database_Name");
$sql="SELECT ModelNo FROM Table_Name WHERE Manufacturer = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>ModelNo</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ModelNo'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Found this online here somewhere.

Swapped this in: `echo '<option value="'.$Manufacturer.'">'.$Manufacturer.'</option>'`;

Added this instead:

```
$q = isset( $_GET['q'] ) ? $_GET['q'] :'WW';
```

The query works fine now.

```
$sql="SELECT ID, ModelNo FROM IE_STARSYSIE_stock WHERE Manufacturer = '".$q."'";
```